# How to add a command hook into setuptools setup?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, setup.py

I am using setuptools Version 0.9.6 and want to add a command hook into `setup`, following the description shown [here](https://github.com/tarekziade/blog/blob/master/entries/extending-setuptools-adding-a-new-command.md) or [here](http://ziade.org/2007/09/30/extending-setuptools-adding-a-new-command/). I have created a class `MyCommand` derived from `setuptools.Command` within the same `setup.py` file and I am trying to add this hook as follows:

```
setup(
  # ...
  entry_points = {
    "distutils.commands": [
      "my_command = MyCommand"]}
)
```

However, the command `my_command` is not recognized, i.e. `python setup.py my_command` gives an error

```
error: invalid command 'my_command'
```

Maybe I do need to refer to my command in a different way? Or are there changes to the used version 0.9.6 of `setuptools`? How to do it right?

Comment: [setup tools adding command](http://ziade.org/2007/09/30/extending-setuptools-adding-a-new-command/)  ..... Hope this helps

Comment: You refer a page I already linked in my question. I followed the procedure but I did not get it to work.

Comment: I got it but some other way .. see below the answer

Comment: Note that what the documentation describe _does_ work, it however *requires* the package providing the specified command to be installed already, so this is a chicken and egg problem - if the package to be installed needs that exact command but not already available, only then follow the answer. If the command is meant to be *reused* by other packages, follow the documentation and register the entry point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add your command in cmdclass instead thats what i found.

```
setup(
cmdclass = {'my_command':MyCommand},
)
```

Type :

```
>>> python setup.py --help-commands
```

Will list your command in `Extra Commands`

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know if there is a way to add default parameters when instanciating this command ?